# Does twillo verify supports custom sms code verify?

Tags: twilio

My goal is achive custom sms code login like over 6 digits also include a-z alphabet, But I am not sure twillo sms code is customizable, All I found on offical document is they provide 4-10 code (4-10 characters), But I am not sure `characters` are also include a-z alphabet, any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve your goal  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to send custom verification codes but you need to contact [Twilio Sales](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) if you want to use this feature. Then, you can use the following snippet to send them:

```js
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.verify.v2.services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                .verifications
                .create({
                   customCode: '867530',
                   to: '+15017122661',
                   channel: 'sms'
                 })
                .then(verification => console.log(verification.sid));
```

Here's also the [docs page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/customization-options#custom-verification-codes).

Comment: Can I validate `customCode` by use `.verificationChecks`? Because I have no validation logic in my system. AII I have is code generation logic

Comment: Yes, I just tested it and it works same as the variant without custom code